# Two Identical Code Segments, Different Results

Tags: c++, file-io

All I need to do is a simple read from a file in the same directory, but for some reason it refuses to work.

It works perfectly fine in this quick test one I made after I had problems, and outputs the number of entries in the text file.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <cstdio>

int main()
    {
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    freopen ("7.txt", "r", stdin);

    while (cin >> a)
        ++b;

    cin.clear();

    fclose (stdin);
    freopen ("7.txt", "r", stdin);

    cout << b << '\n';

    fclose (stdin);
}
```

EDIT: Wow I'm sorry to everyone who tried wrapping their heads around this. It was pretty late when I posted this, but I thought I finished. Apparently not. Now upon reopening my file to post the code in it, I realize that I moved everything into a folder before, but apparently when I tried to run the actual thing, it saved back outside of the folder, so it couldn't open "7.txt".

Problem solved I guess, sad waste of space seeing as how it wasn't even complete O_o, sorry.

EDIT2: Okay now I'm confused. I had a temp account on this computer, but when I logged into this account to ask a different question, this one as I meant to post it the other night showed up. I wasn't even on this computer while asking it. Not sure why it wasn't posted like that if it was all ready to be though.

Comment: why are you reading from a file like that? why not ifstream? and where are the two identical code segments mentioned in the title? why do you increment b, then close the file, then open it again, output b, and close the file again? what is your plan? i relly can't make any sense of it.

Comment: I just edited the post, but I'm pretty sure that's where your confusion was coming from. There were supposed to be 2 code blocks there and more text, but I guess I was too tired, or turned off the computer while on another tab without realizing this was incomplete. Think I hit tab-enter at one point accidentally and went back in to re-edit it. Maybe I just forgot to hit save? In any case, updating it made me realize what went wrong. About your ifstream, I've always used freopen, I just find it easier. I've been meaning to switch for some time. We didn't exactly learn either so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best "guess" is that you are trying to re-read the same file. If this is the case then you could try this :

```
std::ifstream file("7.txt");
std::string line = "";
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
  //do something
}
//reset file pointer
file.clear();
file.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
//re-read file
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
  //do something else
}
```

Please try and formulate better questions in the future.

Comment: I'm going to straight out tell you it wasn't that, as when I open it again, it starts at the beginning (and works if you reset the cin EOF flag via cin.clear()). When I tried doing a loop for the count and one for cout'ing the values, in the teest, it worked fine. Again, I'm really sorry about the question being incomplete. I did mention the problem in the edit though.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but any interaction between `freopen`, `fclose` and `cin` is implementation defined at best (and most likely undefined behavior).

Comment: freopen does work as intended, it allows use of cout and cin to read/write if you open the file for that purpose, but as I edited, it was incomplete when I posted it :/

Comment: @chris Could you point out the clauses in the standard which guarantee this?  (I know that there is some linking between `std::cout` and `stdout`, but I didn't think it when that far.)

Comment: Okay, to be honest, I was just blindly using this function before as that's how I learned to do file I/O one time in CS club, and never really looked it up. After looking up `freopen` in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/) I found out that `freopen` will attempt to close any file associated with the stream given (`stdout`) and redirect usage of this stream to the file it is given. Since `std::cout` is directed to the stream `stdout`, it is then redirected to the file you give `freopen`. You can do the same thing in command prompt by saying `dir>myFile.txt`.

Comment: Where does it say that `std::cout` is directed to the stream `stdout`.  Usually (I think VC++ is the only exception), `std::cout` will go directly to the OS.  (On the other hand, the C standard requires `freopen` to close the current system level file descriptor.  If the following open returns the same file descriptor---which will usually be the case for `stdout`---then `std::cout` will effectively have been redirected.  I don't think that the standard requires this, however.

Comment: Here's Wikipedia's bit on `stdout` in case you're interested: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) The last sentence is the one of particular interest.

Comment: @chris Not that it's particularly good, but how is it relevant.  We're talking about `std::cout`, which isn't mentioned there.

Comment: I would think this was what we were looking for: "The file descriptor **for standard output** is 1 (one); the POSIX <unistd.h> definition is STDOUT_FILENO; the corresponding <stdio.h> variable is FILE* stdout; similarly, **the <iostream> variable is std::cout.**"

Comment: @chris The important point, which makes it generally work, is that `freopen` is specified to close the underlying system stream, and reopen it in some way---in other words, to modify what `1` refers to (under Posix).  But there's still nothing about C++; `cout` could (none do) duplicate the file descriptor, for example, so that a later `freopen` didn't affect it.  Or `freopen` could use the original Unix `dup`, rather than `dup2`, with the result that the `FILE` struct would contain a different file descriptor than `cin` (and I don't know what you're quoting, but it isn't Posix).

Comment: It was just the last sentence in the section the link from 4 posts ago goes to on Wikipedia.

Comment: @chris In other words, not Posix.  The behavior here is defined by the C standard and Posix.